# Как передать значения для полей класса, который объявляется через интерфейс

Tags: c#, интерфейс

Заголовок скорей всего не передает сути вопроса. Имеется два интерфейса:

```
public interface IAttackParameters
{
    double MagicAttack { get; set; }
    double PhysicAttack { get; set; }
}

public interface Player
{
   int Health { get; set; }
   IAttackParameters AttackParameters { get; set; }
   // other fields...
}
```

Эти интерфейсы находятся в библиотеке и ничего не знают о том где они потом реализуются.

Так вот вопрос в следующем, как реализовать данные интерфейсы и задать значения для полей AttackParameters.

```
public class Player : IPlayer
{
   public int Health { get; set; }
   public IAttackParameters AttackParameters { get; set; }

   public void SetAttackParameters()
   {
        AttackParameters.MagicAttack = 10; // не работает
        IAttackParameters.MagicAttack = 10; // не работает
   }
}
```

Говорят что можно так:

```
public class Player : IPlayer
{
   public int Health { get; set; }
   public IAttackParameters AttackParameters { get; set; }

   // Explicityly implement my interface
   IAttackParameters IAttackParameters.AttackParameters 
   {
       get { return AttackParameters; }
   }
}
```

но что-то не красиво как то и не факт что будет работать. Может есть какой то более простой способ, так как ситуация должна быть довольно часто встречающейся.

Comment: А почему вы не хотите добавить класс, реализующий интерфейс `IAttackParameters`?

Comment: реализовать **в любом случае** нужно два интерфейса. Чтобы заработало, достаточно просто инициализировать значение поля _AttackParameters_  новым объектом. Например в конструкторе

Comment: Если вы пишете «не работает», вы автоматически обязаны описать, как именно не работает. Не компилируется — тогда какое сообщение об ошибке? Бросает исключение — тогда приведите тип и текст исключения.

Comment: Я согласен что реализация интерфейса IAttackParameters решило бы все вопросы, но тут мне не нравиться то что я в класс Player добавлю реализацию интерфейса IAttackParameters c названием класса скажем (PlayerAttackParameters) а этого нет в интерфейсе IPlayer. Почему то мне кажется что это потом может повлиять в будущем? Да и в интерфейсе IPlayer можно будет удалить строку IAttackParameters AttackParameters { get; set; } так как она не будет использоваться в реализации, так может дойти и до того что и интерфейс удалят за ненадобностью)))

Comment: @ArtemHohryakov Вам не нравится правильно. В таком случае классу `Player` интерфейс передают в конструкторе: `public Player(IAttackParameters aParams) { AttackParameters = aParams; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Делаем реализацию обоих интерфейсов:

```
  public class AttackParameters : IAttackParameters
  {
    public double PhysicAttack { get; set; }
    public double MagicAttack { get; set; }
  }

  public class Player : IPlayer
  {
    public int Health { get; set; }
    public IAttackParameters AttackParameters { get; set; }

    public Player()
    {
      this.AttackParameters = new AttackParameters();
    }

    public void SetAttackParameters()
    {
      AttackParameters.MagicAttack = 10;
    }
  }
```

В итоге, наружу из `Player` торчит только интерфейс `IAttackParameters`, реализации могут быть любыми, можно пользоваться.

Comment: При создании нового обьекта Player пишет (cannot convert Player to IPlayer), такой вариант решения был первым, и даже если сделать cast к IPlayer, то такая программа скомпилируется но при первом обращении к классу будет Exception. В общем решил остановиться на самом логичном, и реализовать все интерфейсы. Буду решать проблемы по мере поступления. Всем спасибо!

Comment: @ArtemHohryakov, предложенный вариант логичный и правильный, а вы при создании объекта Player что-то делаете неправильно, судя по всему. Покажите код инициализации.

Comment: newPlayer = new Player()
                    {
                        AttackParameters  = new AttackParameters()
                        {
                            MagicAttack = 10,
                            PhysicAttack = 10
                        }
                    }; Конструктор в классе только по умолчанию, возможно в этом проблема конечно...

Comment: @ArtemHohryakov а где конкретно происходит ошибка конвертации (cannot convert Player to IPlayer)?

Comment: AttackParameters = new AttackParameters()  подчеркивает красным и предлагает сделать cast. Я все написал как предложил monk в первый раз, так что все работает уже.

Comment: Простите дурака забыл унаследовать класс от интерфейса и ищу проблему в другом месте. Только сегодня обнаружил данный недочет. public class AttackParameters : IAttackParameters. Теперь все работает как часики.

Answer (score 0):

Интерфейсы требуют реализации. Но ваше 5-ое чувство Вас не обманывает, и то что вы хотите, реализуется с помощью Dependency Injection.  Способ используемый для уменьшения связанности кода,неплохим выбором будет [Ninject](http://www.ninject.org/), как это работает хорошо объясняется [тут](https://professorweb.ru/my/ASP_NET/mvc/level2/2_3.php)

Comment: Мне кажется, писать что-то в стиле "лучшим выбором будет <DI framework title>", это слегка некорректно. Особенно учитывая тот широкий выбор, который имеется.

Comment: Совет очень интересный, я уже пробовал DI контейнеры, но не очень подружился. Пока не жмет поэтому оставляю ну второй план. Как нибудь обязательно возьмусь, спасибо!

Comment: Согласен, данная реализация контейнера на мой взгляд наиболее популярна в учебных статьях.